# Running Keras in R and python

Tags: python, r, keras

I am intrigued by the `keras` package, which allows running the well known deep learning library from within R. The benefits of running keras (and tensor flow and theano) without leaving R are obvious.

What I am unsure of is whether there is a possibility to share the intermediate result - i.e. a trained neural network - with colleagues on python workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just save your model (architecture + weights + optimizer state) [`keras_save`](https://rdrr.io/cran/kerasR/man/LoadSave.html). And then your colleagues could load it from `python`. More information [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#savingloading-whole-models-architecture-weights-optimizer-state).
Also, @Jindra Lacko noted, that `keras_save` is from `kerasR` - a different package than `keras`. Better solution - [`save_model_hdf5`](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/save_model_hdf5.html) function.

Comment: are you sure the model.save() is a `r` (and not `python`) call?

Comment: I see. Now it makes sense! :) Thanks